# Taking the sup inside the expectation for an infinite collection of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(X_t)_{t \in T}$ be an infinite collection of real-valued random variables, where $T$ is a topological space (not necessarily countable).
Under which conditions on $t \rightarrow X_t$ and on $T$ it true that
$$
\sup_{\substack{K \subset T: \\ |K| < \infty }} \mathbb{E} \big ( \sup_{t \in K} X_t   \big ) = \mathbb{E} \big ( \sup_{t \in T} X_t   \big ).
$$
where $\mathbb{E}$ is the expectation. Is continuity of the function $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ for example necessary/sufficient? Do we need $T$ to be separable?

It seems to me that one direction is always true:
$$
\sup_{\substack{K \subset T : \\ |K| < \infty }} \mathbb{E} \big ( \sup_{t \in K} X_t   \big ) = 
\sup_{\substack{K \subset T : \\ |K| < \infty }}\int d P(\omega) \, \, \sup_{t \in K} X_t(\omega)
\leq 
\sup_{\substack{K \subset T: \\ |K| < \infty }}\int d P(\omega) \, \, \sup_{t \in T} X_t(\omega)
= \mathbb{E} \big ( \sup_{t \in T} X_t   \big ).
$$

Comment: Isn't this just monotone convergence theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One direction is true as you showed. Further

$$\mathbb{E} \big ( \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}^n} X_t)=\int dP(\omega) \sup_{t\in \mathbb R^n }X_t(\omega)$$

Let now $t\in\mathbb R^n$, then also $t\in K_i \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ for some $K_i\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, (in fact we can choose $K_i=\cup_{j´\leq i} t_j$). Then

$$\leq\int dP(\omega)\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{t\in K_i }X_t(\omega)$$

And we are left with exchanging a limit and integral. As noted by the comment, this is the dominated convergence or monotone convergence theorem. Hence if $\sup_{t\in K_i }X_t(\omega)$ is bounded or monotonically increasing, we have

$$=\sup_{\substack{K \subset \mathbb{R}^n : \\ |K| < \infty }} \mathbb{E} \big ( \sup_{t \in K} X_t   \big ).$$

Comment: Ho Dole, shouldn't the less or equal rather be a $\geq$?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm No, why would it be less or equal? We covered the whole "path" of possible $t$s.

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm For a maximizing path $t_1,t_2,t_3,...$ we can select $K_1,K_2,K_3,...$ But we can also select a different sequence... but indeed, it also works the other way around and in fact we can use strict equality. But since you already proved the other side without any conditions that's not necessary...

Comment: Thanks. Are we using the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is separable? Would the same fact hold if in place of $\mathbb{R}$ we had any other separable space $T$ (not necessarily countable)?

Comment: We did not change the place of the inner supremum. It should be clear that $\lim_i A_i$ is smaller or equal to $\sup_{ K\subseteq \mathbb R, A\in K} A$, using the same argument as above. That said writing the whole thing as a limit seems possible too, however we want to keep the supremum inside the integral. Finally, If a sequence is increasing, then $\sup t_i = \lim_{i\rightarrow \infty} t_i$. But if it is not obvious use the inequality.

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm No, only basic properties of $\sup$.

Comment: I believe one needs to show that a countable union of sets $K_1$, $K_2$, $\dots$, covering the whole space exists...

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm Supremum is either a real number or diverges to infinity. If it is a real number there exists a set of rationals that converge to it from below. We can choose $K_i$ as the union of the members of this sequence up to $i$. And similarly if it goes to infinity...

Comment: I mean that this is necessary because of having a countable union, which is necessary for dominated convergence.

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm Can you specify what do you mean in more detail?

Comment: I mean that this is necessary because we need to have a countable number of sets... without countability one cannot write the limit as $i$ goes to infinity. More precisely $$a_i : = \sup_{t \in K_i} X_t(\omega)$$ must be a countable sequence.

Also what you wrote seems to suggest that:
$$
\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \sup\limits_{t \in K_i} X_t(\omega) \leq 
\sup\limits_{t \subset T} X_t(\omega),
$$
but I agree that if the sequence $K_i$ covers the whole set $T$ then the identity holds.

Comment: In the easy case where $X$ has continuous sample paths and $T$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ (which is the most common by far) you can restrict the supremum to rational values of $t$, which would solve your problem. If $T$ is separable and $X$ is continuous, the same trick applies. In all generality, it's not obvious that $\sup_T X_t$ will be measurable.

Comment: Thanks Charlus, where is continuity required?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm In that case $X$ is bounded a.s.

Answer (score 0):

We can bypass the conditions imposed by the dominated convergence theorem or monotone convergence theorem if $X_0 \geq C$ for some constant $|C| < \infty$ (this is almost always satisfied since most processes are deterministic at time $0$ and the supremum can only increase from there).
As you noted, if $\sup_{t\in T} X_t$ is measurable and $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in T} X_t]$ exists, then one side is trivial.

For the other side (I'm assuming here that $T$ is a subset of the real axis that includes $0$), you want to assume for example that the paths of $X$ are càdlàg almost-surely (this is less restrictive than continuity, for instance, all Levy processes are càdlàg), so that $\sup_{t\in T} X_t = \sup_{t\in T\cap \mathbb{Q}} X_t$ almost-surely, where $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rational numbers.
Then, by Fatou's lemma:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\Big[\sup_{t\in T} X_t\Big] - C
&= \mathbb{E}\Big[\sup_{t\in T\cap \mathbb{Q}} (X_t - C)\Big] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\Big[\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{t\in K_n} (X_t - C)\Big], \quad \text{where } K_n := T \cap \mathbb{Q} \cap [-n,n] \\
&\stackrel{\mathrm{Fatou}}{\leq} \liminf_{n\to \infty} \, \mathbb{E}\Big[\sup_{t\in K_n} (X_t - C)\Big] \\
&\leq \sup_{K\subseteq T : |K| < \infty} \mathbb{E}\Big[\sup_{t\in K} (X_t - C)\Big] \\
&= \sup_{K\subseteq T : |K| < \infty} \mathbb{E}\Big[\sup_{t\in K} X_t\Big] - C,
\end{align*}
where the last inequality follows from the fact that $K_n$ is a specific finite subset of $T$.

Comment: thanks for the answer, my assumptions are however more general since it is not necessarily the case that the set of rational numbers is a subset of T or that T is a one dimensional set... I think that separability of T should be necessary...

Comment: Yes, if you want to generalize the argument, you need $T$ to be separable. You just replace $\mathbb{Q}$ with a dense subset. Similary the càdlàg assumption has to be adapted. And the "time 0" would be replaced by a point where the process or field is deterministic. Otherwise, you can use the DCT.

Comment: @FrédéricOuimet how is using Fatou's there different than using monotone convergence?